# INSERT INTO does not return until canceled

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, insert-into

i am using sqldevlepoer and trying to execute an statement like below,

```
INSERT INTO users
(first_name, last_name)
VALUES
('john', 'smith');
```

but nothing is returned until i stop the operation manually .... it just hangs, 
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing just that, because we need more info, but maybe you have another session with a begin transaction and it was never commited or rollbacked.

Comment: Would it help if I restart the Oracle services? im goign to try it.

Comment: Probably, that will kill all current connections.

Comment: have you tried using commit after the insert statement?

Comment: The statement never finishes executing unless i stop it.-

Comment: the table probably is locked by other active session.

Comment: No other sessions open.....

Comment: what does `v$session` say the session is waiting on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, just that, because we need more info on your question, but maybe you have another session with a begin transaction and it was never commited or rollbacked.

Comment: That didnt help im afraid ... im goignt to reboot my machine.

Comment: reboot did not help. just hangs.

Comment: The connection was left mid air on the Oracle server side which required a lot of untanggling to sort out - thanks for your help - it was the issue you pointed at it just wasnt local.